# Java - JPanel & its contents how to set bounds

Tags: java, swing, user-interface, jpanel, jscrollpane

I have 3 JPanels on my JFrame. Anyhow the JPanels expand vertically and horizontally as the JFrame is being re-sized they are bound to JFrame.

I am wondering how do i set JScrollPane that is inside one of the JPanels to be bound to that JPanel so if that JPanel is being re-sized so is the JScrollPane inside it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you have a `JPanel` containing only one `JComponent` which should scale with the panel, one of the easiest layout manager options is the `BorderLayout` and adding the contents in the center

```
JPanel panel = new JPanel( new BorderLayout() );
JComponent componentToAdd = ...;
panel.add( componentToAdd, BorderLayout.CENTER );
```

There is a whole [Swing tutorial](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/layout/using.html) on the different layout managers which describes in which situations the differentmanagers are most suited

Comment: How about if the JPanel containt a JComboBox and bellow it JScrollPane

Comment: A `BorderLayout` can only contain one component in each location, and only the `CENTER` location stretches it contents horizontally and vertically (see latest paragraph of the BorderLayout javadoc). So it depends on your requirements whether you can use it or not (e.g. by adding the `JComboBox` to the `NORTH` and the scroll pane to the `CENTER`)

Answer (score 2):

This would require you to give the JPanel a correct layout such as a BorderLayout, GridLayout,  BoxLayout, or other depending on the need (but not JPanel's default layout -- FlowLayout -- which does not change the preferredSize of the components held).. If a BorderLayout, then add the JPanel `BorderLayout.CENTER` (or in another position again depending on need). If you are not familiar with the basic layouts, you will want to read through and study the tutorials which can be found here:

[Lesson: Laying Out Components Within a Container](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/layout/index.html)